# Nodejs returning from try...catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running the following from node 9.5:

```
const { lstatSync, readdirSync } = require('fs');
const { resolve } = require('path');

const isDirectory = source => lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source =>
  readdirSync(source).map(name => resolve(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);

try {   
    const apiRoutes = getDirectories(__dirname + '/api');

    if (apiRoutes.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('API root must contain directories');
    }

    console.log(apiRoutes);

    return apiRoutes;

} catch (e) {
    console.error(`${e.name}: ${e.message}`);
}


//Why don't these fire?
console.log(apiRoutes);
console.log('foo');
```

Assuming there are two directories in *api*, the first `console.log(apiRoutes)` in the try block logs:

```
[/basedir/api/dir1,/basedir/api/dir2]
```

However, I can't get anything after the try block to run. If I don't return `apiRoutes` in the try block I get an `undefined` error.

How do I return a value from the try block?

Why doesn't *foo* get logged?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far... I'll have a look at the `const` scope. But it doesn't explain why logging out the string *foo* isn't working?

Comment: OK, I changed `const apiRoutes` to `var apiRoutes` and removed `return apiRoutes`. I can now log *foo*. I'm presuming that because I'm in node, that returning, is return from the module?

Comment: @sanspoon, right. if you `return`, you return out of the current function; the `module` in your case.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apiRoutes` `const`ant is scoped within the `try` block.

Refactor the code to either move the `console.log`s within the `try` block, or change to defining `apiRoutes` with `let` in the outer scope; and setting its value within the try block by calling `getDirectories`.

---

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global or local to the block in which it is declared. Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables. An initializer for a constant is required; that is, you must specify its value in the same statement in which it's declared (which makes sense, given that it can't be changed later).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1):

You may need to declare apiRoutes outside of the try/catch. Once the try/catch completes you lose scope of the variable.